# Form being submitted on clicking image

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```
<form action="telecallerinfo.php?action=modify&id=<?php echo $id;?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table class="panel1">
    <tr>
        <td>Caller Name:&nbsp;<input name="tele_caller" type="text" size="15" value="<?php echo $tele_caller?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
        <input name="submit" id="submit" type="image" src="images/submit.gif" width="60" onclick="this.form.submit();"/>
        <input name="cancel" id="cancel" type="image" src="images/cancel.gif" width="60" onclick="window.location.href='telecallerinfo.php';"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

but then I am clicking on the cancel image. The form is being submitted. How to stop it because I want only the page to be refreshed. Is there any way of giving reset functionality to an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="telecallerinfo.php"><img src="images/cancel.gif" alt="DON'T FORGET ALTERNATIVE TEXT"></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Image inputs submit the form when clicked. You need to `return false` in your event handler to stop the normal action of the button taking place.

```
<input name="cancel" id="cancel" type="image" src="images/cancel.gif" width="60" onclick="window.location.href='telecallerinfo.php'; return false;"/>
```

In theory the same should hold for the submit-image, but actually you should just discard the event handler and let the default action submit the form when clicked.

For a button that just navigates to a page you would be better off using a simple link.

> Is there any way of giving reset functionality to an image?

If you really wanted:

```
<img onclick="document.getElementById('someform').reset();">
```

But it'd be better to do it without JS using a real reset button:

```
<button type="reset">
    <img src="images/cancel.gif" alt="Reset"/>
</button>
```

This will give you a button graphic around the image, but you can get rid of that with CSS:

```
border: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; background: transparent;
```

Are you sure you want a ‘reset’? They're rarely useful, and often annoying if accidentally clicked thinking they're submit buttons...

Comment: thanks for the information "Image inputs submit the form when clicked". so

Answer (score 2):

You may try this if you want it as an image:

```
<button type="reset">
<img src="image location" alt="Reset" />
 </button>
```

It works but, **RESET buttons are destructive and should not
be used**, except in situations where destruction of user input is really
desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one

```
    <input type="image" src="butup.gif" alt="Submit button">
```

Some browsers wont support to "alt" tab so there is another way:

```
   <html>
   <body>
   <form action="example.cgi" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="login">
   <br>
    <input type="image" src="submit.gif">
   <input type="image" src="reset.gif">
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: may be your browser ignoring "alt".

Comment: Try this one:<html>
<body>
<form action="example.cgi" method="post">
<input type="text" name="login">
<br>
<input type="image" src="submit.gif">
<input type="image" src="reset.gif">
</form>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="reset" name="Reset" id="button" value="Reset" />
```